# Uploading local maven repository to archiva

Tags: java, maven, gradle, archiva, artifact-deployer

I am setting up a local repository using Apache Archiva. After setting up now I need to copy the libraries that got downloaded into my local maven repository into archiva. Currently I am manually copying it but it is very tedious process and I am planning to automate it using some scripts. Is there any better approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to write a plugin for this [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export) which is able to copy jars and poms for all dependencies in all `Configuration`s (including transitive dependencies). You might be interested in [this code](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/dependency/export/MavenDependencyExport.groovy#L45)

Note: I've got a failing test [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/lazan/dependency/export/MavenDependencyExportTest.groovy#L69) because I can't currently get the parent pom xml via the Gradle API's. I raised a feature request in Gradle [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2809)

There's a suggestion on the issue to use the [IvyPot plugin](https://github.com/ysb33r/ivypot-gradle-plugin)... I haven't tried this myself but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for it. I will have a look. I too have decided to do the same